# AnalogOnScreenController or Joystick for libGDX

Tags: android, andengine, libgdx

has someone implements on screen controller for libGdx? simething like AndEngine [AnalogOnScreenController](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/engine/camera/hud/controls/AnalogOnScreenControl.java)

thanks

Answer (score 4):

For joystick you have touchpad in libgdx. 
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Touchpad.html